# How to get a refrence to a switch inside the actionbar in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar

This is the code of the menu main_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/newy"
>
<item
    android:id="@+id/myswitch"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/switch_layout"
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="always" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/empty"
    android:title="options"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:visible="true"
    android:orderInCategory="101"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_overflow1">

    <menu>

        <item android:id="@+id/action_help"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
            android:title="help" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_settings"
            android:title="settings"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    </menu>

</item>
</menu>
```

The first item of id "myswitch" is the switch,
this is it's actionlayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    >

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switchForActionBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:paddingRight="18dp"
    android:text=""

    android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
    return true;

}
```

Is there a way to get a reference to this switch in onCreate?
I want full access to the switch not only when it is clicked(using onOptionsItemSelected which doesn't work by the way; it was unable to detect when the switch was pressed unless clickable is set to false).
I tried too many ways from similar questions but in vain...

The function of this button is to toggle the wifi (WifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false) or WifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true)).

When the program starts it should detect whether the wifi is initially turned on or off and set the switch to the corresponding state.

Comment: have you tried actionBar.findViewbyId(R.id.switchForActionBar)?

Comment: How do I get a reference to the actionbar??

Comment: I tried this:    `Switch switchy;
        Window window = getWindow();
        View v = window.getDecorView();
        switchy = v.findViewById(R.id.switchForActionBar);`                                          but switchy is null

Comment: Also you can't apply getViewById on a menu object